# Overwriting text on terminal with Java, issue with Console.read*

Tags: java, console, terminal

I know there are hundreds of questions asking how to update already written text on console and I know I can do it printing the \r character.

My issue comes when I use Console.readPassword or Console.readLine which creates a new line and later I can't overwrite it.

I think that my issue isn't related to something special about the Console.read* methods but to new lines. \r goes to the start of the current line, I need to be able to go to the start of the previous N line and start overwriting from there. Or just clear the entire screen.

Any ideas how can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, this is terminal dependent, and with simple Java means there is no way to do this for all consoles.

Many terminals (at least in unixoid systems) support [ANSI-escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_sequences), so you can there write something like "\u001B[1;5H" to move the cursor to line 1, columnn 5.

Comment: I guess that works, I'll leave this unanswered for a while to see if someone comes with something more clean. Thanks.